# driver error for geb-gradle-saucelabs integration

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, geb

I am trying to run below build.gradle with saucelabs integration . Below is GebConfig.groovy

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import geb.driver.SauceLabsDriverFactory
import geb.buildadapter.BuildAdapterFactory

//driver = { new ChromeDriver() }

def sauceBrowser = System.getProperty("geb.saucelabs.browser")
if (sauceBrowser) {
    driver = {
       def username = System.getenv("username")
       assert username
       def accessKey = System.getenv("accesskey")
       assert accessKey
       new SauceLabsDriverFactory().create(sauceBrowser, username, accessKey)
    }
}
```

I am setting `geb.saucelabs.browser` prop in `build.gradle` according to [this](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.10.0/cloud-browsers.html#saucelabsdriverfactory). Full build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: "geb-saucelabs"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }    

    dependencies {
       classpath 'org.gebish:geb-gradle:0.13.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repository-saucelabs.forge.cloudbees.com/release" }
}

dependencies {
           def seleniumVersion = '2.45.0'
           def phantomJsVersion = '1.1.0'
           def groovyVersion = '2.4.3'

    //groovy
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$groovyVersion"

    // selenium drivers
     testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:$seleniumVersion"
     testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
     //testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
     testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
     testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
     testCompile("com.github.detro.ghostdriver:phantomjsdriver:$phantomJsVersion") {
     transitive = false
    }

    // geb
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.10.0"

     // spock
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'

    //junit
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-junit4:0.10.0"
    testCompile "junit:junit-dep:4.8.2"


    sauceConnect "com.saucelabs:sauce-connect:3.0.28"

        }

sauceLabs {
    browsers { 

       chrome_mac

    }
    task { 
       testClassesDir = test.testClassesDir
       testSrcDirs = test.testSrcDirs
       classpath = test.classpath
    }

    account { 
       username = System.getenv("username")
       accessKey = System.getenv("accessKey")
    }


}

test {

            System.setProperty("geb.saucelabs.browser ","browserName=firefox platform=LINUX version=19")
            systemProperties "geb.build.reportsDir": "$reportsDir/geb"
        }
```

but I recieve error and I think driver is not configuring correctly, whats missing in confirguration?

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by setting the env variables on mac in `.profile` and `.bash_profile` in this way

```
export SAUCE_USERNAME=username
export SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY-youraccesskey
```

Before it was adding quotes to both

Answer (score 1):

What's the command you use to run your test? You shouldn't be fiddling with `geb.saucelabs.browser` system property for the `test` task but use the `chromeMacTest` task as per documentation you link to in your question.

Comment: Update: above username and password error resolved but I get `Execution failed for task ':openSauceTunnelInBackground'.
> Timeout waiting for tunnel to open` now.

Comment: And on console it also says `sauce-connect: 24 Jul 19:32:14 - Error: response: {"error": "Not authorized"}.` But I've used this username and key with `webdriverio` test and I was able to see my test at sauce labs dashboard.